# Branching shared projects in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, branching-and-merging

We have a SQL database that is accessed by several different software products (all with their own Visual Studio solutions).

I'm wanting to create a database project so we can have version control of the database objects.

What I want to know (if it's possible at all) is how do I share the database project across all of the solutions and allow branching per solution?

I've made a couple of test solutions/projects, and I'm able to link the shared database project to another solution by going File->Add->Existing Project, however, when I create a branch of that solution, it doesn't seem to create a branch of the database project and the new branched solution has an invalid reference to the database project.

Is there a way to do this? (if so, how?)

Answer (score 0):

In this circumstance I would put all three into the same solution. That would allow me to version and build together.

Branching in this curcomstance is a bad idea as you will just end up with multiple products to support. This is especially common for shared SQL projects.

If you have time to refactor then you could put a service interface in top of the database to allow you to version. If you build a single solution with Restfull API's and your Database you could much more easily both use that api while maintaining data integrity. Its real hard to move the database forward for one application without affecting the other without a service interface that you can version.